# Does anyone know if this bit of Microsoft doc is correct?

Tags: windows, winapi

While struggling with a dialog sizing issue, I had to look at the SDK documentation for `GetSystemMetrics()`. Looking at `SM_CXFIXEDFRAME`, I found:

> The thickness of the frame around the perimeter of a window that has a
>   caption but is not sizable, in pixels. `SM_CXFIXEDFRAME` is the height
>   of the horizontal border, and `SM_CYFIXEDFRAME` is the width of the
>   vertical border.

this left me a bit startled as I would expect a `SM_CX` value to be a distance in the `X` direction, a width (as are `SM_CXBORDER` and `SM_CXCURSOR`), where here it is very clearly stated as being a height. Does anybody know if this is actually correct or simply a documentation error?

Comment: It's a documentation bug.

Comment: It says **clearly** in the `nIndex` parameter:  *Note that all SM_CX** *values are widths and all SM_CY** *values are heights*. So it is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I never experienced the Windows Documentation to be invalid.
I'd highly doubbt they made a mistake in the documentation.
For why this is a CX-Value, this may come from the fact that this is the horizontal border (in x-direction) and hence an attribute of the x-direction of the window.

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason, but that would apply to the border value I mentioned as well. I agree that the documentation is probably correct as you say, but wanted to ask if anybody knew that this was the case here.

Comment: @TimBergel For the cursor value, it describes the width of the cursor and not any border-concerned value. The CX-Border value may mean the width of the border not the height, as this is concerned with the dimension of the border and not the location.

Comment: The FixedFrame value is also concerned with the width of a border and not its location...

Comment: *I never experienced the Windows Documentation to be invalid.* really!?